# Total sum of top 3 value occurrences in groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to get the total sum of value occurrences in col `Z` for every `W,X,Y` group and only keep the top 3. The sum of occurrences of all other rows in `W,X,Y` group should be grouped under "Other"

I was able to get the sum for each value in a new column `COUNT`, but not sure how to limit this to top 3, and how to group all others under "Other". Any help would be much appreciated...

```
data_grouped = data.groupby(["W", "X", "Y"])

for group_name, group in data_grouped: 
  res = group.groupby(["Z"]).size().reset_index(name="COUNT")

  More processing stuff and store in db...
```

**INPUT**

```
| W | X | Y | Z |
| - | - | - | - |
| a | d | x |   |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| a | d | f |   |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | h |
| b | d | f | i |
| b | d | f | i |
| b | d | f | i |
| b | d | f | i |
| b | d | f | i |
| b | d | f | i |
| b | d | f | i |
| b | d | f | j |
| b | d | f | j |
| b | d | f | j |
| b | d | f | k |
| b | d | f | k |
| b | d | f | l |
| b | d | f | l |
| b | d | f | m |
| b | d | f | m |
| b | d | f | n |
| b | d | f |   |
| b | d | f |   |
| b | d | f |   |
| a | d | f |   |
| a | d | f |   |
| c | e | g |   |
| c | e | g |   |
| c | e | g |   |
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
| Z     | W | X | Y | COUNT |
| ----- | - | - | - | ----- |
| h     | b | d | f |  12   |
| i     | b | d | f |  7    | 
| j     | b | d | f |  3    | 
| Other | b | d | f |  7    |  <-- sum of k,l,m,n
and so on...
```

Comment: Please provide an easily reproducible input

Comment: Hi mozway, what would you consider “easily reproducible”? This is a snapshot of millions of rows I have in db.

Comment: A minimal sample, sufficient to reproduce the logic, in the form of a DataFrame constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` to find the counts; then `groupby.head` to get the top 3. Then filter out the top 3 values and use `groupby.sum` to get the total of `OTHER`. Finally, `append` this back to `top3`:

```py
counts = df.value_counts(['W','X','Y','Z'])
top3 = counts.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).head(3)
out = (top3.append(counts[~counts.index.isin(top3.index)].reset_index(level='Z')
                   .assign(Z='Other').set_index('Z', append=True).squeeze()
                   .groupby(level=[0,1,2,3]).sum()).reset_index(name='COUNT'))
```

Output:

```
   W  X  Y      Z  COUNT
0  b  d  f      h     12
1  b  d  f      i      7
2  b  d  f      j      3
3  b  d  f  Other      7
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your latest code. `counts[~counts.index.isin(top3.index)` doesn't seem to work when there is only 1 element which is missing from `top3.index`. It returns `'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'groupby'`

Comment: Example: https://pastebin.com/zPDTDSED

Comment: I think it's `squeeze()`. It returns scalar `1` in this case, which you can't group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of completing this:

```
df = df[df["Z"] != " "]   # EDIT

data_grouped = df.groupby(["W", "X", "Y"])
grand_output = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Z", "W", "X", "Y", "COUNT"])

for group_name, group in data_grouped: 
    # output dataframe for group
    output = pd.DataFrame(columns=[])
    res = group.groupby(["Z"]).size().reset_index(name="COUNT")
    # create dataframe of res and W, X, Y columns
    output = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([list(group_name)]*len(res), columns=["W", "X", "Y"]), res], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    output.columns = ["W", "X", "Y", "Z", "COUNT"]
    # sort and sum
    output.sort_values(["COUNT", "Z"], ascending=False, inplace=True)
    if len(output) > 3:
        others = output.iloc[3:]["COUNT"].sum()
        output = pd.concat([output.iloc[:3], pd.DataFrame([list(group_name)+["other", others]], columns=["W", "X", "Y", "Z", "COUNT"])])
    # append to final output
    grand_output = grand_output.append(output)

grand_output  # Edited with blank Z rows dropped
#Out: 
#       Z  W  X  Y COUNT
#0      h  b  d  f    12
#1      i  b  d  f     7
#2      j  b  d  f     3
#0  other  b  d  f     7
```

Comment: it's a bit different from the expected output, no?

Comment: No, the output was for group b, d, f for W, X, Y.  It doesn't include the other groups.  At least, that is how I have interpreted the output given.

Comment: Only thing is I have included the count for `Z = ""`.  Have changed that.

Comment: My bad, didn't see there were other W,X,Y values lol. But still it's different from the expected output. For example, the count for `b,d,f,Other` is 7 in OP's expected output (which is what we get if we drop NaNs) but 10 here. So seemingly, OP's dropping NaNs, but they also say "*and so on...*", so I don't know which one's correct.